# Why isn't it possible to determine a particle's position without changing its velocity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

So, I think understand the premise of the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, but it seems to me that someone would be able to create a device which would be able to measure the position of a particle by emitting equal radiation from multiple vectors such that interference cancels itself out. Am I missing something?

Comment: There is no way to get a quantum state that simultaneously has well-defined position and momentum. You are missing that the uncertainty principle is *not* a statement about the precision of measurements.

Comment: The uncertainty principle says that a particle with a precisely defined value for velocity **does not have* a well-defined value for position. It doesn't mean we cannot measure the position, it means there is no precise position to measure. The measurement of one value changes the state of the particle such that it destroys the other value (to put it simplistically)

Comment: This is all about [commutators](https://www.eng.fsu.edu/~dommelen/quantum/style_a/commute.html).

Comment: @ACuriousMind Actually, my question is more of "Is it possible to create a test for position which negates the side effects for velocity?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, for example, you wanted to shoot two photons from opposite directions in order to detect the position of the particle at a particular time, you would have to know exactly where to send them in order for their momenta to cancel out. In other words - you would have to know the position. But if you did know the position, and shot these two photons, then how would you extract the velocity information? Since the collisions of the two photons cancel each other out, and there is no impact on the velocity of the particle, there is also no information about the velocity of the particle that is transferred.

I think the uncertainty principle lives another day.

**UPDATE**

In order to preserve a couple of the comments, I reproduce them here:

> **@cwallenpoole**:
>  That said, wouldn't it be possible, knowing velocity, to have a knowledge of maximum possible position, and using that create a continual test (or series of tests) which eventually result in the current position of the object along that velocity?
>
> **@Floris**:
>  Your proposed experiment gives the potential to determine after the fact the position and velocity of a particle at an earlier time without such knowledge being useful to predict what happens next. "I see particle at location x1. Some time t later I see it at x2. I know how long it too to get to x2 so I know both its velocity and position." But that is not simultaneous, and in fact you only know the average velocity over the trajectory (how do you know what trajectory it took? How would you prove it?)

Comment: For the last line, +1 :)

Comment: No doubt it would live. At best I can think of [racecar on a train type solutions](https://xkcd.com/675/).

Comment: That said, wouldn't it be possible, knowing velocity, to have a knowledge of maximum possible position, and using that create a continual test (or series of tests) which eventually result in the current position of the object along that velocity?

Comment: Kind of like a zipper... my guess is that "no it wouldn't" because you'd need information to travel faster than the speed of light in order to make sure you did not run any tests which interfered with the velocity of the particle after the position of the particle was determined.

Comment: Your proposed experiment gives the potential to determine _after the fact_ the position and velocity of a particle _at an earlier time_ without such knowledge being useful to predict what happens next. "I see particle at location x1. Some time t later I see it at x2. I know how long it too to get to x2 so I know both its velocity and position." But that is not _simultaneous_, and in fact you only know the _average_ velocity over the trajectory (how do you know what trajectory it took? How would you prove it?)

Comment: @Floris Giving you the answer. Could you add that last comment to it? I think that a valuable point.

Comment: @cwallenpoole - done.